# Как производить математические операции с массивами

Tags: sql, perl

Добрый день. Есть два массива которые я получаю путем запроса к базе.
Первый

```
    my $dbquery1 = $db->selectall_arrayref("select * from DPTDAT where ID = 1");
foreach my $rowMPT_DAT1 (@$dbquery1) {
  my ($f1, $f2, $f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14) = @$rowMPT_DAT1;
}
```

Второй

```
    my $dbquery2 = $db->selectall_arrayref("select * from DPTDAT where ID = 2");
    foreach my $rowMPT_DAT2 (@$dbquery2) {
my ($ff1, $ff2,$ff3,$ff4,$ff5,$ff6,$ff7,$ff8,$ff9,$ff10,$ff11,$ff12,$ff13,$ff14)=@$rowMPT_DAT2;}
```

Мне нужно сложить например каждый `$f11` и `$ff11`
Подскажите как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Лучше пусть это сделает база за Вас. Но в целом, кто мешает сделать обычный цикл?

Comment: Мне нужно еще изменять содержимое $f11 и $ff11 там не простые числа, с ними не получится сразу производить мат. операции. А по поводу цикла, я могу просто в цикле сделать два запроса и внутри уже производить операции?

Comment: два запроса сделать можно, если аккуратно. В Вашем коде есть одна особенность - он может выдвать различные результаты. Дело в том, что если в select не указан порядок сортировки, данные могут отдаваться в произвольном порядке. И если в случае sqlite порядок можно угадать, то в случае postgress порядок может быть удивительным:)

Comment: f11 и ff11 это вообще то обычные скаляры, а не массивы и с ними работать будет скорее всего не удобно. особенно перебирать f1 f2 f3 и т.п. лучше бы они массивом оставались. Да вы можете и в одном цикле выбирать записи (записей то у вас кстати много или одна ?)  и идти циклом или map по массиву полей.

Comment: в библиотеках есть чудесная функция [zip](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#zip-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3). Он делает половину нужной работы. - объеденяет два массива в один.

Comment: В рабочем коде использовать форму "select *" чревато ошибками, лучше явно задавайте названия полей "select id, name, etc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Array::Each;
use DDP;

my $X = [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
my $Y = [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
my @Z;

my $set = Array::Each->new( $X, $Y );
while( my( $x, $y ) = $set->each() ) {
    push @Z, $x + $y;
}

p @Z;
```

Вывод:

```
[
    [0] 4,
    [1] 6,
    [2] 8,
    [3] 10
]
```

> Мне нужно еще изменять содержимое `$f11` и `$ff11`

Для этого можно использовать третье значение, возвращаемое `Array::Each::each()`:

```
while( my( $x, $y, $idx ) = $set->each() ) {
    # здесь $idx - индекс текущего элемента, соответственно,
    # доступ к элементам исходных массивов:
    # $X->[$idx], $Y->[$idx]
}
```

---

Ну или совсем просто (только здесь нужна явная страховка от разных размеров массивов):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DDP;

my @X = ( 2, 3, 4, 5 );
my @Y = ( 2, 3, 4, 5 );
my @Z = map 
{ 
    # что-то делаем с $X[$_] и $Y[$_],
    # но в конечном итоге возвращаем
    # сумму элементов: 
    ($X[$_] || 0) + ($Y[$_] || 0)
} 0 .. ( $#X > $#Y ? $#X : $#Y );

p @Z;
```